Looking to replicate Step.Finance DeFi aggregation, but can't find the right commands
I'm writing a little Node.js tool to see my balances across the Solana universe, but have only found ways to see the balances in my actual wallet (getParsedAccountInfo, getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner, etc).
I'm looking for ways to see my accounts on margin.fi and Solend.Fi.
I've created a connection and am sifting through the sdk commands but haven't found the one for my query. Do I have to find their mint addresses and then cross-check against my transaction history? That seems excessive.
I appreciate any help and direction!

You'll likely need to find SDKs from the different dapps to properly understand and deserialize the data in their accounts

Thanks @JonC. I can see on Solscan for example that the transactions involve these different platforms, so I'm hoping there is a Solana SDK example that doesn't involve each platforms SDK.
